# Sum of $p$ terms of an A.P. is $q$, and the sum of $q$ terms is $p$; find the sum of $p+q$ terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The sum of $p$ terms of an arithmetic progression is $q$, and the sum of $q$ terms is $p$; find the sum of $p+q$ terms.

Answer (as listed at the end of the book): $-(p+q)$

Comment: What is your question? If it is "How do I get the answer?", can you tell us what you have tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$S_{n}=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$

Where $a$ is the first term, $d$, the common difference, and $n$ he no. of terms

So,

$S_{p}=\frac{p}{2}(2a+(p-1)d)=q$

$S_{q}=\frac{q}{2}(2a+(q-1)d)=p$

Subtracting the two :

$q-p=ap+\frac{p^2d}{2}-\frac{pd}2-aq-\frac{q^2d}2+\frac{qd}2=a(p-q)+\frac{d(p-q)(p+q)}2-\frac{d(p-q)}2$

Divide by $(p-q)$ to get to:

$\frac{1}{2}(2a+((p+q)-1)d)=-1$

Now, multiply both sides by $p+q$ to get at your answer.

Can you do it now?

Comment: I can't get $\frac{1}{2}(2a+((p+q)-1)d)=-1$ by subtracting the two equations. Can you clarify please ?

Comment: @DavidSebastian take a look at the edit

Comment: Thanks a lot but how did you see this relation ?

Comment: @DavidSebastian We just have two equations, so we try to manipulate the two, add or subtract to arrive at something useful. Best of luck !! :)